# Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax() to controller Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I want to pass an array of strings as well as a string variable to the controller but it says parameter not present.

here is my javascript

```
function updateIssueHandler() {
var keyArray = [];
bootstrap_alert_hide('#form_errors');// cleans previous errors
$('input:checkbox[name=key_checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    keyArray.push($(this).val())
});
if (keyArray.length == 0) {
    var errorMsg = document
            .getElementById("js.i18nMessage.emptyUpdateTickets.id").value;
    bootstrap_alert('#form_errors', errorMsg)
}
var labels = document.getElementById('labelsTextBox').value;
var b = {
    "lab" : labels,
    "keys": keyArray
};
//console.log(addl);
console.log(keyArray);
$.ajax({
    url : '/jirabatchapp/JqlUpdate/',
    data : b,
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        window.alert("done");
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UpdateLabelController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/JqlUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateIssue(@RequestParam(value = "lab") String a,@RequestParam(value = "keys") String k ) {

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println("finally!");
    return "success";
}
}
```

I get an error saying HTTP request error 400 Required string parameter lab not present.

What am i doing wrong? if I only pass labs, then it works, but if i want to pass both parameters it is throwing me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
var b = {
    "lab" : labels
    "keys": keyArray
};
```

to

```
var b = {
    "lab" : labels,
    "keys": keyArray
};
```

Comment: sorry, i have done that. changed it in edit. still throwing same error

Comment: What is keyArray value in console.log?

Comment: It looks that you are passing array of String in keys and you are retrieving only String on Controller side. If you want String then pass keyArray.toString(); value in your b variable

Comment: ["ACADPLY-4432", "ACADPLY-4388"]
0
:
"ACADPLY-4432"
1
:
"ACADPLY-4388"
length
:
2

Comment: even when i do @RequestParam(value = "keys") String[] k in the contoller, still throwing the same error!

Comment: @RequestParam(value = "keys[]") String[] k

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a string as parameters

Just do this : `data : JSON.stringify(b)`

EDIT :

Try : `data: $.param(b)`

Comment: Still throwing Http status 400 required string "lab" not present

Comment: when i do this, it throws Http status 400 required parameter string 'keys' not present

Comment: but you have lab this time ? strange ^^ can you show me querystring parameters in the network tab from your debugger tools ?

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/jirabatchapp/JqlUpdate/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1105
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 04 Oct 2016 11:00:19 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*

Comment: Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:55
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=96CA5D33BDFB6D37C4FF3361A3401E85
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/jirabatchapp/JqlSearch
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
lab:lol
keys[]:ACADPLY-4432
keys[]:ACADPLY-4388

Comment: ok keys is an empty array :/ you send this : `lab = lol`  `keys = []`

Comment: its showing me this lab:lol keys[]:ACADPLY-4432 keys[]:ACADPLY-4388. i dont think its empty.

Comment: click on 'view source' (neart QueryString Parameters title) and paste me the result please

Comment: got it! had to do @RequestParam(value = "keys[]") String[] k